# Ubuntu 17.04, Mounted Drives, Samba Share, Need to CRUD from Windows machines

Tags: windows, samba, fstab, 17.04, smb

I've been trying to get a few things working on my Ubuntu desktop server for quite some time now and after reading quite a few threads, trying out multiple solutions, I figured it's time I ask the community.

**Background**
I've got an old desktop that I've installed 16.10 *(but recently updated to 17.04)* on and use it as my media server and local dev machine. I then have a Windows 10 machine that I use to map drives to it and then edit code via my IDE's and run various CLI tools and other things required.

**The problem**
The issue I run into is when I install packages via `node/bower/git`, or create any files on the Ubuntu machine via the CLI, those files/folders are not editable from my Windows machine and I need to run a `sudo chmod 0777 -R locationfolder/`

This is not something I want to continue to do and I would like to be able to seamlessly add/edit/delete/move files on either machines and not have to run into `chown` or `chmod` issues - and preferably not `777` everything and to have to continue to run this when new files are pulled/added.

**What I can and have done**

- I do have the drives being mounted on the Ubuntu at startup, and they are being mounted as my local user `sga`.
- I then do also have those mounted locations shareable in my `smb.conf` file and
- I can access those from my Windows machine.
- I can then also map those drives to a lettered drive in Windows and be happy days
- When I add new files in windows, they are added as my local ubuntu user `sga`

Hopefully this is enough background and describes the issue enough, but if not please ask and I will update accordingly. I have also added the necessary conf files below so you can checkout if I may have miss configured anything.

**fstab**

```
#Entry for /dev/sda1 :
UUID=924b3a00-6bb1-4b7a-bcb1-c13efb84df49 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
#Entry for /dev/sdd2 :
UUID=88529CC1529CB582   /home/sga/media/Movies  ntfs-3g auto,users,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=000,utf8    0       0
#Entry for /dev/sdc2 : 
UUID=F046FE3746FDFE62  /home/sga/media/TV-Series        ntfs-3g auto,users,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=000,utf8     0       0
#Entry for /dev/sdb2 :
UUID=60EAEC94EAEC67AC   /home/sga/media/TV-Series-Cont  ntfs-3g auto,users,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=000,utf8    0       0
#Entry for /dev/sda5 :::
UUID=36881df5-86a1-4d0a-9422-a1221eea332d       none    swap    sw      0       0
```

*Please note that my www folder is not here, but as soon as I solve a different issue with an MBR on a separate drive, I will add it here.

**smb.conf**

```
[global]
  workgroup = SGC
  usershare allow guests = yes

[Public Server]
  path = /home/sga/Public/www
  browseable = yes
  guest ok = yes
  read only = no
  create mask = 777
  public = yes
  writeable = yes

[Movies]
  path = /home/sga/media/Movies
  browseable = yes
  guest ok = yes
  read only = no
  create mask = 777
  public = yes
  writeable = yes

[TV Series]
  path = /home/sga/media/TV-Series
  browseable = yes
  guest ok = yes
  read only = no
  create mask = 777
  public = yes
  writeable = yes

[TV Series Cont]
  path = /home/sga/media/TV-Series-Cont
  browseable = yes
  guest ok = yes
  read only = no
  create mask = 777
  public = yes
  writeable = yes
```

*Please note, I've only added the items I have customised in `smb.conf` - Everything else I have kept default. 
**Also good to note that my `Public Server` resides on my root drive that Ubuntu is installed on with the other shares are mounted drives.

Ok, I hope this covers it and I hope someone is able to help... would really love to edit freely on my machines and not have to run the `chmod` commands often.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: So it this post TLDR?

Comment: maybe the question isn't specific enough -- it could probably be more generalized to find the solution